# What exactly is caching?

Tags: php, caching, frameworks

Someone asked me to cache the XML call im pulling in to prevent server trouble. But now my question is, what exactly is caching, and how do i do it?

Hope to find some answers here.

Is it a way to save the XML output to a file, and then use that file? But how do i check if there are any updates than, or when somebody closes the browser? Or do i store the XML in a SESSION or COOKIE?

Comment: Instead of recomputing something every time you need it, you save the value the first time and then look it up when you need it again.

Comment: Presumably downloading the data and storing it somewhere locally for later reads, based on a time-out value, as opposed to re-requesting the (assumed unchanged) XML each time from its source.

Comment: [Several other SO posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+cache+xml+file) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching is the action to remember your calls during a limited time in order to prevent unnecessary calls.

For exemple, it can be like this :

1. You check if there is something already cached.
2. There is nothing, so you make your call.
3. You save the answer of your call for a limited time.

Next time you will check the cache, you won't call, but just user the saved answer.

You can be inspired by this script : http://www.finalwebsites.com/snippets.php?id=49